# Replace AppController to other name in CakePHP 2.0

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, acl

I want to ignore AppController in CakePHP 2 and make my own AppController like

```
class abcController extends Controller {

}
```

And then I want to use Auth and ACL in abcController.
What do I need to change for this in my project?
Currently when I change AppController to another name and include Auth component in that then child classes are not able to access Auth Component.

Comment: Why Do you need it?

Comment: No one should ever need that.

Answer (score 1):

Can't imagine why you'd do that.  If you're trying to replace something so fundamental, you shouldn't be using the framework at all..

Comment: I've two sections Frontend, Admin.
I want to add Auth component on admin section, not on frontend section.
If I include Auth in AppController then It becomes for all controllers. 
So I want a separate controller that behaves like AppController where I can include Auth for all admin section controllers.

Comment: Ah!  A very standard thing for many sites, and not one that requires this approach at all.  Sounds like you're confusing authentication and authorization :-)  http://miftyisbored.com/complete-tutorial-admin-routing-cakephp/ See here for a fairly good, if outdated, outline of how to go about requiring extra authorization for some users: http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/creating_an_admin_section_with_cakephp_updated

Comment: Basically, make a user model, and require that people login when they want to access some parts of the site.  No overriding of important core parts at all..

Comment: Sorry I keep hitting enter at inappropriate times, forgetting you can't..

Comment: Thanks, George for your support (Link provided by you: miftyisbored.com/complete-tutorial-admin-routing-cakephp helped me a lot)